# Being personally involved in a cause - recommended or not?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

A common sense adage is that one shouldn't be personally involved in the subject they are put in charge of. Being personally involved makes it hard to stay completely objective. For example, if someone has had altercations with immigrants, they probably shouldn't be put in charge of legislation for border control.

On the other hand, in the Jewish world, I am aware of many many examples of people who started a charity or gemach, directly from a personal experience. They had a sickness, or lost someone, and then started a charity to raise awareness and help others going through the same. It seems that being personally involved is often a wake up call to action on something that has been neglected.

I understand this is a wishy washy question, and probably doesn't involved many if any concrete halachos, but do we have any sources that help us understand if the above is a contradiction, or why the former is not recommended, but the latter is (seemingly) encouraged? Any general advice on how to approach these topics?

Comment: Assuming this is a valid question, we need to understand why starting a cause is counter indicated by being involved in it.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I agree. What would be a good way to do that? What I am getting at is usually when a cause is started to "fight" a negative force, the cause has a strong potential to turn into a greivance movement, because the people who start and join it are usually victims of said negative force and therefore are prone to overreaction. For me, this is common sense and there are many examples, especially in modern times. I gave an example in my opening paragraph. Lastly - yes, I agree this isn't necessarily a valid question. Waiting to see what others say.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE you might know what I am talking about: Hashem made men from chessed and women from gevura, yet we see that the roles and jobs He gave are the opposite. In a typical frum home, men are the disciplinarians and women the care givers. Why? I believe the answer is that Hashem does it this way so we aren't personally involved in the job we are given. For men, chessed is personal, so if they are the care givers, it can get inflammatory. For women, gevura is personal, so when something unjust happens, it's easier for them to take it personally, due to their neshama

Comment: There's a difference between judging people and just trying to help.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Rb Wosner (*derashos*) says this is so men and women can each be *mashlim* their natural aspects (which seems obvious).

Comment: You seem to assume the Jewish people you see are immune to that issue, but really the same issue applies to people who start a charity for some rare disease a relative died of. Probably more lives would be saved sending all that money to research breast cancer (ie. something more common). The gemach that you want to start isn't necessarily the one that will do the most good.

Comment: @DoubleAA no assumptions in the question except that being personally involved is probably not ideal.

Comment: You said "the latter is (seemingly) encouraged"

Comment: @DoubleAA the word "seemingly" was there to imply that I am not assuming that, but opening that for question